# Is there a way to specify the track color for a progress view?

Tags: swiftui

I can set the progress indicator color as follows:

```
ProgressView(value: 50.0, total: 100.0)
                    .padding()
                    .accentColor(Color(.red))
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to set the color for the track.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to set it using a modifier in SwiftUI, but you can always create your own style: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/customizing-progressview-with-progressviewstyle

Answer (score 0):

Setting track color doesn't seem to be supported by SwiftUI yet.

Here's a solution using `UIViewRepresentable`

```
struct ClearTrackProgressView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let value: Float
    let animated: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIProgressView {
        let progressView = UIProgressView()
        progressView.trackTintColor = .clear
        return progressView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIProgressView, context: Context) {
        uiView.setProgress(value, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Note: I added `animated` to control the animation. You can remove it if you don't need it.